# Converting double to String in order to read a txt file

Tags: java, string, arraylist, double

I am doing a exercise of a banking account with a txt file, my acount have name(String), acc number(String), balance(double). I need to convert the **balance** (column[2]) in to a double.

```
public static ArrayList<Account> readAccounts(Scanner input){
    String row;
    String[] column;
    ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    while(input.hasNext()){
        row = input.nextLine();
        column = row.split(";");
        Account account = new Account(column[0], column[1], column[2]);
        account.toString();
        accounts.add(account);
    }
    return accounts;
}
```

Comment: *I need to convert the balance (column[2]) in to a String.* I have **tremendous** news; `column[2]` **is** a `String`. Or I'm missing something very relevant here.

Comment: You are right, what i need is the opposite, i will fix the post, thank you!

Comment: *what i need is the opposite* `Double.parseDouble(column[2])`

Comment: Another FYI Just because something is numeric and has a decimal point doesn't mean it has to be a floating point number. There is a fixed decimal called BigDecimal that is easier to deal with.

Comment: Thank you both! I will close the question

Comment: @NathanHughes There is also [`Currency`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html). If you want to model money specifically.